# Deskewing MNIST dateset

Tags: ocr, skew, mnist

I'm currently working on the digit handwritten recognition problem. I found that many state-of -art algorithms adopt some preprocessing methods to the mnist dateset, such as deskewing and jittering (I don't know what 'jittering' is). I googled for a long time but found nothing about the specific methods or algorithms that could be used to deskew mnist dateset. Does anyone have ideas about how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can find an already decoded version of the MNIST dataset here: http://mnist-decoded.000webhostapp.com/

Answer (score 5):

I have Googled long and hard to find this as well but never managed to until I saw this paper:

> Teow, Loo-Nin, and Kia-Fock Loe. "Robust vision-based features and
>   classification schemes for off-line handwritten digit recognition."
>   Pattern Recognition 35.11 (2002): 2355-2364.

Read section 4.2.  They have described a procedure for **deslanting** their images.  I'm not sure if this is the same as **deskewing** but it's the closest thing I have been able to find.

Hope this help and would appreciate if someone can confirm whether **deslanting** is the same as **deskewing**.

Answer (score 1):

Deskewing is taken from LeCun's 1998 paper [http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98.pdf].

> The deskewing computes the second moments of inertia of the pixels
>   (counting a foreground pixel as one and a background pixel as zero)
>   and shears the image by horizontally shifting the lines so that the
>   principal axis is vertical.